# How to store data in Common Data Service of Power Platform from an external application?

Tags: common-data-service, power-platform

I would like to insert new records to an entity in a Common Data Service database of Power Platform from an external application that is outside the Microsoft Ecosystem. I don't know if Power Platform exposes a kind of API to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes CDS expose an API to consume I leave you the documentation link --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/get-started-dynamics-365-web-api-csharp

Also you can user Power Query for that --> https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/load-data-from-external-data-sources-to-the-common-data-service-using-power-query-2/

Now you need to know wich option is the best for you aproach.

Comment: That is good to know, but how would you do this in Bulk?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498559/how-can-i-do-bulk-inserts-into-the-common-data-service

Comment: Well in the API there are ways to do it, you will find my response in the link provided by you. Another way is use Dataflows is a powerful tool to do that easily.