# How can I do bulk inserts into the Common Data Service?

Tags: azure, common-data-service, dataverse

I have 1000 records that I need to sync daily from an API. I am currently bulk inserting them into a SQL Database, however I would like to use Dataverse/a Common Data Service database instead.

The Logic App connector seems to do 1 record at a time and the SDK does PUTS and POSTS. How can I either insert 1000 records into the Common Data Service in bulk OR somehow synchronise my SQL DB with the CDS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no another way to do that without programming. You can extended your Power Automate Flow with Azure Functions to insert these records in a single transaction.

In this link explain how can be do it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api#when-to-use-batch-requests

Please let me know wtih anything

Comment: Thanks - what are your thoughts on bulk inserting into SQL and then using a triggered Power Query to transform and sync it into Dataverse?

Comment: Sure this is another good way. You can use Dataflow for it. With Dataflow you can configure to make this execution periodically based on you schedule. This is a nice tutorial where talks about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dataflows/data-sources?tabs=power-bi-service

Answer (score 0):

If you want to regularly ingest data (1000 rows) into Dataverse (CDS), then use Dataflows. The following link to MS Docs describes how to set up scheduled bulk data updates. It is therefore a pull rather than push model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-and-use-dataflows